# Importing duty-free 750 ml wine bottles into Turkey

Tags: customs-and-immigration, turkey, alcohol, duty-free

I am intending to bring a few bottles of Australian wine into Turkey as a present for friends. Each bottle contains 750ml of wine (14.5% alcohol).

The [customs rules](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/turkiye_ye-ait-gumruk-bilgileri.tr.mfa) says:

> Muafiyet kapsamındaki eşya tür ve miktarları şu şekildedir:
>
> ALKOLLÜ ÜRÜNLER
>
> 1- Alkol derecesi % 22’yi geçen alkol ve alkollü içkiler 1 lt.
>
> 2- Alkol derecesi % 22'yi geçmeyen alkol ve alkollü içkiler 2 lt.

Strictly speaking, my wine does not fall under the item #1 as it is below 22% alcohol, which means I only can take 2L of wine, which is no more than 2 bottles.

However, a lenient interpretation could assume that if I am allowed to take 1L of 22%+ alcohol *additional* to the 2 l of 22%−, then there is no point in requiring that 1L of alcohol to be at least 22%; a weaker percentage should be permissible too. This logic would allow either:

- 3 bottles (1 bottle within the 1L of 22%+ concession and 2 bottles within the 22%− one); or even
- 4 bottles (750 ml × 4 = 3 l = 1 l + 2 l)

Would I be able to assume/argue the lenient approach? How many bottles can I take?

Comment: You can also take three or four and declare and as such indicate you are willing to pay tax.

Comment: If your interpretation were the right one, then I would expect the rule to be worded differently: "up to 3 L of alcohol, of which 1 L may be above 22%".  But I do not know Turkish; perhaps there are some subtleties of grammar or idiom that would make it unambiguous to a Turkish speaker.

Comment: I do not think you will get anywhere with "arguing" a particular interpretation.  The customs officers know the rules, and they know how they intend to interpret them - your argument is not going to change their mind.  Since you are unsure, declare the wine, and if told to pay duty, just pay it.

Comment: @NateEldredge your approach essentially negates the whole point of making duty free rules available to travelers. Only the officers know how to interpret them, so get everyone declare everything. I'd rather take less bottles than pay tax on the extra ones, but equally I'd hate to take less if I could take more duty free.

Comment: @Willeke I am asking this question because I would rather take less bottles than pay tax on the extra ones. At the same time, I would hate to take only 2 if I could take 3 or 4 tax-free.

Comment: "your approach essentially negates the whole point of making duty free rules available to travelers": no it doesn't: you're still able to bring limited quantities of alcoholic beverages into the country without paying duty.  What you *want* to do, however, is to exceed the limit, and doing that requires paying duty.  If a US resident has an $800 exemption, they can import a duty-free piece of jewelry worth $800 or less without paying duty, but if the piece is worth more than $800 they may be required to pay.  Duty free shopping isn't useless, it just promotes smuggling.

Answer (score 6):

> Would I be able to assume/argue the lenient approach? How many bottles can I take?

Most likely no. The two criteria are mutually exclusive. Either the alcohol volume is < than 22% or the volume is >= 22%. Therefore, the rule is extremely clear: **you can bring up to 2L of alcohol < 22% volume, and up to 1L of alcohol >= 22% volume**.

Since you wish to bring wine, you are allowed two 750ml bottles of wine duty free. You cannot use the allowance for the >= 22% volume alcohol since wine contains < 22% alcoholic volume.